# Why no 'install' rules generated by cmake install()?

Tags: cmake

I'm running cmake v 3.18.0 on ubuntu 20.04

My install() command doesn't generate any install rules within the generated Makfile. CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
# Static library
add_library(mbaux
            STATIC 
            mb_cheb.c mb_delaun.c mb_intersectgrid.c mb_readwritegrd.c 
            mb_surface.c mb_track.c mb_truecont.c mb_zgrid.c)


target_include_directories(mbaux
                           PUBLIC
                           .
                           ${X11_INCLUDE_DIR}
                           ${GMT_INCLUDE_DIR}
                           ${GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR}
                           ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mbio)

# Static library
add_library(mbxgr
            STATIC 
            mb_xgraphics.c)


target_include_directories(mbxgr
                           PUBLIC
                           .
                           ${X11_INCLUDE_DIR}                      
                           ${GMT_INCLUDE_DIR}
                           ${GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR}
                           ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mbio)
                           
# Install
message("set up mbaux install targets")
install(TARGETS mbaux DESTINATION cmake-example/lib)
install(TARGETS mbxgr DESTINATION cmake-example/lib)
```

Yet when I look in the generated Makefile I see my message "set up mbaux install targets" but there is no reference to the destination 'cmake-example/lib', and no specific 'install' target that I can see.

Thanks!

Comment: The generated makefiles have logic and targets spread across multiple files.  Does `make install` work?

Comment: Ah, I see the destination referenced in cmake_install.cmake - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just because you seem new to CMake, a couple words of advice re: install rules...

First, avoid hard-coding destinations. You always want to `include(GNUInstallDirs)` (even on Windows). This module defines a number of standard cache variables for configuring installation destinations.

See [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) for the full list, but the following are the most relevant here:

- `CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR` - the path below the installation prefix where the include structure should exist. Typically, and by default, `include`.
- `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` - the path below the installation prefix where libraries should be stored. Typically, and by default, `lib`. Often overridden on multiarch systems to include the target architecture, such as `lib/aarch64-linux-gnu`.
- `CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR` - the path below the installation prefix where package-specific data should be stored. Typically, and by default, `share`.

In CMake 3.14+ these are used as the default destinations for `install(TARGETS)`. This should be all you need:

```makefile
include(GNUInstallDirs)

install(
  TARGETS mbaux mbxgr ...
  EXPORT mb-targets
  RUNTIME COMPONENT mb-runtime
  LIBRARY COMPONENT mb-runtime
  NAMELINK_COMPONENT mb-development
  ARCHIVE COMPONENT mb-development
  INCLUDES DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}"
)
```

Don't forget to guard your include paths with `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:...>` in the main build (to allow `INCLUDES DESTINATION` above to overwrite them):

```
target_include_directories(
  mbaux
  PUBLIC 
  "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mbio>"
)
```

You almost certainly do not want to use the `${<PACKAGE_NAME>_INCLUDE_DIRS}` variables here, either. Instead use `target_link_libraries` with the relevant imported targets; this will set up include paths automatically.

```
target_link_libraries(mbaux PRIVATE X11::X11)  # likely similar for GMT/GDAL
```

When you *are* required to specify a destination, you generally want to use the `TYPE` argument instead of `DESTINATION`. If you must use `DESTINATION`, use a project-specific cache variable as its argument; for example:

```
# will install headers to ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/**/*.h
# without mbio prefix, remove the trailing / to include mbio 
# in the path
install(DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mbio/"
        TYPE INCLUDE
        COMPONENT mb-development
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")

set(MB_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/cmake/mb"
    CACHE STRING "Installation directory for CMake package files")

install(EXPORT mb-targets
        DESTINATION "${MB_INSTALL_CMAKEDIR}"
        NAMESPACE mb::
        FILE mb-targets.cmake)
```

Finally, you should never read or set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` from within the CMakeLists.txt file. Instead you should rely on relative paths (as done above) or the `$<INSTALL_PREFIX>` generator expression (in exceptional circumstances) to avoid making your installation script non-relocatable.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Stephen Newell, cmake spreads rules and logic across multiple files - and I now see where they are (in this case, cmake_install.cmake)